# Unable to populate nested array to dropdown with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- I am trying to populate json to dropdown list, mainly **main category, sub category and sub sub category** .
- I am able to populate main category and sub category, but i am unable to populate subsubcategory.
- Also only based on main category, sub category should be populated, similarly based on sub category, sun sub category dropdown should be filled with options.

Please help.

**Code**

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.chooseCategories = [{
    categoryId: 1,
    catName: "men",
    desc: "some description",
    subcat: [{
      key: "topWear",
      value: "m-top-wear",
      subSubCat: [{
        key: "Ma",
        value: "M-A"
      }, {
        key: "Mb",
        value: "M-B"
      }]
    }, {
      key: "bottomwear",
      value: "m-bottom-wear",
      subSubCat: [{
        key: "Ma",
        value: "M-A"
      }, {
        key: "Mb",
        value: "M-B"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    categoryId: 2,
    catName: "women",
    desc: "some description",
    subcat: [{
      key: "topWear",
      value: "w-top-wear",
   subSubCat: [{
        key: "Wa",
        value: "W-A"
      }, {
        key: "Wb",
        value: "w-B"
      }]
    }, {
      key: "bottomwear",
      value: "w-bottom-wear",
   subSubCat: [{
        key: "Ma",
        value: "M-A"
      }, {
        key: "Mb",
        value: "M-B"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    categoryId: 3,
    catName: "kids",
    desc: "some description",
    subcat: [{
      key: "topWear",
      value: "k-top-wear"
    }, {
      key: "bottomwear",
      value: "k-bottom-wear"
    }]
  }];
  var locationsArr = $scope.chooseCategories.map(function(item) {
    return item.subcat;
  });

  var temp = $scope.chooseCategories.map(function(item) {
    return item.subcat;
  });

  $scope.finalArr = locationsArr[0].concat(locationsArr[1]).concat(locationsArr[2]);

  $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.chooseCategories[0].categoryId.toString();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
  Main category::<select ng-model="selectedCountry">
    <option ng-repeat="x in chooseCategories" value="{{x.categoryId}}"> {{x.catName}}</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
 Sub category:: <select ng-model="selectedsubcategory">
    <option ng-repeat="locations  in finalArr" value="{{locations.key}}"> {{locations.value}}</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  Sub sub category::<select ng-model="selectedsubSubcategory">
    <option ng-repeat="locations  in finalArr2" value="{{locations.key}}"> {{locations.value}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle link is broken

Comment: try with this: https://jsfiddle.net/08z4kb09/18/

Comment: I have updated my question with the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.chooseCategories = [{
    categoryId: 1,
    catName: "men",
    desc: "some description",
    subcat: [{
      key: "topWear",
      value: "m-top-wear",
      subSubCat: [{
        key: "Ma",
        value: "M-A"
      }, {
        key: "Mb",
        value: "M-B"
      }]
    }, {
      key: "bottomwear",
      value: "m-bottom-wear",
      subSubCat: [{
        key: "Ma",
        value: "M-A"
      }, {
        key: "Mb",
        value: "M-B"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    categoryId: 2,
    catName: "women",
    desc: "some description",
    subcat: [{
      key: "topWear",
      value: "w-top-wear",
   subSubCat: [{
        key: "Wa",
        value: "W-A"
      }, {
        key: "Wb",
        value: "w-B"
      }]
    }, {
      key: "bottomwear",
      value: "w-bottom-wear",
   subSubCat: [{
        key: "Ma",
        value: "M-A"
      }, {
        key: "Mb",
        value: "M-B"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    categoryId: 3,
    catName: "kids",
    desc: "some description",
    subcat: [{
      key: "topWear",
      value: "k-top-wear"
    }, {
      key: "bottomwear",
      value: "k-bottom-wear"
    }]
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
  <select ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="x.catName for x in chooseCategories" ng-init="selectedCategory = chooseCategories[0]">
  </select>
  <hr>
  <select ng-model="selectedsubcategory" ng-options="x.value for x in selectedCategory.subcat" ng-init="selectedsubcategory = selectedCategory.subcat[0]">
  </select>
  <hr>
    <select ng-model="selectedsubSubcategory" ng-options="x.value for x in selectedsubcategory.subSubCat">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's working as expected. But I have one more doubt, now i have one more field in every `subSubCat`array, i.e `otherOptions`, I want these also to be printed on individual subsubcat selection. Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/08z4kb09/26/

Comment: how it should look like and where you want to print?

Comment: it should come after the subsubcat dropdown. If there are any `otherOptions` for particular product, then it should display. For example product with `subsubCat` **T-shirt** has 3 otherOtions va;es, then after subSubCat those 3 should also as a dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks, one last how can i print all the selected values from the dropdown, I tried like ` ng-controller="DemoCtrl as opt"`and then binding every model to `opt.` but it's not working.

Comment: Hey, now I am able to print values, but for `otherOptions`, I am only getting last selected value, not the all values. See this :: https://jsfiddle.net/08z4kb09/29/

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to print `otherOptions` in key-value pair, like `otherOptions 1: pattern1``otherOptions 2: pattern2``otherOptions 3: pattern3`, because i have to map each `otherOptions` to database as well.

Comment: @jitender: you helped with me this `jsfiddle.net/0827yjd9/1`, but now i have one more regarding it.